# Build fails in Android Studio after adding library

Tags: android, build, gradle

I've been using Android Studio 1.0.2 for a while now and have had no problems. I have a fairly simple app that uses Fragments. Originally I was using the built-in Fragment framework as my target devices will be 4.0.2 upwards. However, due to bugs in the Framework on earlier devices I decided to move to using the Fragment support library (why anyone would not use this over the built-in - well, that's another question...)

I added the library, com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0, to my build.gradle, thus:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.1.5'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.1.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

(I already had appcompat-v7 in the list).

All good so far. After converting the fragment manager calls and imports I did a build and got this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library'. Failed to
>   create parent directory
>   'D:\current-projects\android_studio_projects\WallPaintings\app\build'
>   when creating directory
>   'D:\current-projects\android_studio_projects\WallPaintings\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3'

I performed a synchronise and then I did an Invalidate Cache and restart. I then performed another build and got the same result.

Then, after some reading on SO, I discovered you have to perform a "Synch Project with Gradle files". I did this and it worked - compiles up, builds the APK, etc. Fantastic.

However, from that point on, every time I do a Clean or a Rebuild I end up with the same error until I perform the gradle synch.

What is the problem? I can't see what I've done wrong. There is ample disk space and the directory where it attempts to create the things is read/write.

Or is this yet another piece of black-box magic / dark arts that one needs to learn in order to use Android Studio (come back Eclipse - all is forgiven!!)

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but you use support v4 in its 21.0.0 version, and appcompat v7 in its 21.0.3 version. You shouldn't mix them. Use the v4 in its 21.0.3 version too.

Comment: Thanks - well spotted Kernald.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I restarted Studio numerous times and tried other possible solutions but nothing worked - it stubbornly kept getting the same error so I gave up and just went back to working on my app, resigned to having to do a Synch Gradle after a Clean.

Then yesterday it started no longer reporting the error on a clean.

Black magic.

I was never a great fan of Eclipse, but the more I use Android Studio the more I realise this isn't a 1.0 - it's still very much a Beta.

Closing this question as it has been "solved" - all by itself!